# How to use vuejs module on object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following piece of code:

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="" v-model="user.phones">
</div>

<script>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {

      user: {
        phones: []
      }

    }
  }
});

</script>
```

Whenever user writes a phone, I want that to be injected in the `user.phones` model. But since the `phones` model is an array, the number is not being assigned to user.phones

Comment: You just need to pass the index of array on which number should be written

Comment: How? This is a new array, so can I pass just `[0]`?

Comment: It should be set in the index you set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `v-model` for that. If you want to insert a new phone number each time a value is entered, use

```
 <input type="text" name="" @change="(event) => user.phones.push(event.target.value)">
```